# Apache2 mod_proxy modifies content-type for some reason

Tags: apache-2.2, mac-osx, proxy, reverse-proxy, mod-proxy

I am using a local proxy using apache2 to do some development work (OSX 10.8):

```
SSLProxyEngine on

ProxyPass /app https://my.server.org/app
ProxyPass /web https://my.server.org/web
```

Everything works fine, except Apache2 some how overrides the `content-type` response header for html files. If I request `https://my.server.org/app/index.html` the content type is `text/html`, whereas for `http://localhost/app/index.html` I get to see the correct page, but the content type is set to `text/plain` making the browser display unrendered html code. It only seems to happen for html files. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem appeared to be that the back-end server was not setting any `Content-Type` headers for some files due to misconfiguration. When this happens, `mod_proxy` inserts a `Content-Type` based on local configuration like `DefaultType` in Apache.

I have not been able to figure out what caused the different behavior between OSX and Ubuntu, but after we fixed the back-end server to always send a `Content-Type` response header, the problem disappeared.